# SNI proxy TLS session reuse over NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, node-http-proxy, sni

I'm setting up a SNI Proxy to be able to dynamically handle SSL connections on different domains. I'm using an HTTPS server with node-http-proxy (last version) over node.js v0.12 which supports SNI callback.

```
var sniOptions = {
  SNIcallback : function(){
  //dynamically fetch SSL certificate here
  }
}

https.createServer(sniOptions, function (req, res) {
    // node-http-proxy logic routes request here
});
```

All good so far but I haven't find yet a way to reuse the same TLS session. Everytime a request is received a brand new TLS session is created and I want to avoid this.
The only to resources strictly related to the topic are [this issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7113) on Github and this [Paypal blog post](https://www.paypal-engineering.com/2014/04/01/outbound-ssl-performance-in-node-js/).

Any suggestion about it?